# How to split the output of os.path.basename and only take unique output in the same line in yaml dictionary creation?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am creating a dictionary for yaml file generation but am wanting to recover only the unique sample tag of a file labled "Unmap_98_01.fastq" and Unmap_98_02.fastq. There are many files that follw this structure but I want to only recover the Unmap_98 part once. So each unique sample id. I am generating the dictionary as follows:

```
yaml_dict = [{'samples' : [os.path.basename(file) for file in glob.glob(path+"/*."+args.type)]},
     {'path_to_files' : path}]
```

This currently returns Unmap_98_01.fastq and Unmap_98_02.fastq.

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks :)

Comment: (1) The shown code wouldn't work (calling a string and more issues) (2) If you have working code that returns the requested filenames, what is the problem?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Opps put the working code in. I dont want file names I want a subsection of files names that are unique.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to make it clearer what you want. Do you mean "common" when you write "unique"? For instance "Unmap_98_" is common to "Unmap_98_01.fastq" and "Unmap_98_02.fastq". If you know that the file names always follow a structure like "<common_prefix>_<somenumber>.fastq", then you can easily extract the "<common_prefix>" part using string methods `split` and `join`. Also, try to decompose your problem into smaller bits. The part you are trying to get right is the list associated to `"samples"`, is it correct?